# Boost Asio Windows_stream_handler - Async_read_some not called recursively

Tags: boost, boost-asio

Am using boost::asio::windows::stream_handle and used async_read_some method to read data from a named pipe recursively. I associate a read_handler for the async_read_some method. But async_read_some handler is getting called only once, its not getting called further when new message come through the pipe. with trial and error method i assigned the read_handler again to async_read_some method and now its getting called properly. But is the right way of doing or please suggest a elegant way of getting continuous response from the pipe.

```
boost::asio::io_service my_io_service; 
boost::asio::windows::stream_handle pipe( my_io_service);
boost::array<char, 4096> buffer;

void CPublishSubscribeLib::read_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
if(bytes_transferred > 0 )
pipe.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, 150), boost::bind(&CPublishSubscribeLib::read_handler, this, _1, _2));
}
```

Thanks is advance !

Comment: Either `read_handler` gets called with `bytes_transferred == 0`, or `my_io_service::run` exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Boost.Asio, a single asynchronous operation may call the associated handler only once, and then immediately delete all copies of the handler Boost.Asio has created.  Thus, if an `async_read_some` operation is initiated only once, then the *ReadHandler* will be invoked only once.  It is a very common pattern to form asynchronous chains by initiating an operation  from within the handler of the same operation.  In this case, it would be normal to initiate an `async_read_some` operation from within `CPublishSubscribeLib::read_handler`.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question about the right way of obtaining a continuous stream of data from the pipe - sure, read_handler can be called from within itself to handle the next message.  I do that in my code and it works fine.  The important thing to keep in mind is that the thread your read_handler is on needs to be resposive.  That means that it should not take too much time to handle each message.  So, what many recommend is simply copying the message to a buffer, then store it in some sort of container (queue, stack, or vector) that holds the messages, and then notify a worker thread to wake up and process the message.  This is the approach I take in my code.  But, you may not need to do that in your code if the processing is minimal and/or the server does not send many messages.  If you are concerned about performance and memory fragmentation when copying small messages to a buffer from the socket, then you might consider allocating a large wrap-around buffer to store the messages .vs. allocating space for each message as it arrives off of the heap.